# Can't read js file from url - recieve empty html file

Tags: javascript, java, url

I want to read js file as string from url https://www.hellobank.fr/rsc/contrib/script/hb2/js/app/pages/video-bienvenue.js

My code is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
URL url = new URL(jsUrl);
URLConnection cnt = url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = new URL(jsUrl).openStream();
if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(cnt.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding"))) {
  stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
}
// read text returned by server
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = in .readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line).append("\n");
} in .close();
```

Instead of real content of the js I received empty html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.location = "/fr/systeme/maintenance?&ID=12646317151369496393&eq=LSM2TDBW";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody help me to understand what is the problem with that js link  and how to read it properly?

Comment: why don't you just send a request to get the file  ?

Comment: Looking at those URL fragments "system" "maintenance", perhaps the site was down for maintenance when you made the request?

Comment: are you trying to hotlink or is the JS hosted on your own server somewhere?

Comment: @Turnip : valid point...good catch or may be *iff* external, somehow they are redirecting hotlinks! :)

Comment: @Turnip when I open the link via browser it works fine, so the site doesn't seem to be down

Comment: @NoobEditor it's not our server, just link I need to read. how to check the redirection? and what is "iff external"?

Comment: @UsmanRana what do you mean?

Comment: May be it is because you didn't call
[`cnt.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/javascript")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I added the line, it doesn't help

Comment: @MarinaRappoport i really don't get what you are trying to accomplish here but if it is just to read and later use it in your html, why not just include it via `<script>` tag rather than doing an overkill of read then write? or even better, *save* it and use locally unless its copy-right protected!  :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I'm not using it in html. I need to read the js to get specific info from the code.

Comment: @NoobEditor I'm testing landing page that uses that js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send `GET` request, just like you do in your browser.
You could read about how to do it [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-url-content-in-java/).

And your code will be pretty much the same as in the example:

```
    URL obj = new URL("https://www.hellobank.fr/rsc/contrib/script/hb2/js/app/pages/video-bienvenue.js");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString()); //here is the content of the file you need
```

or being more close to your code, it'll be something like this:

```
    String jsUrl = "https://www.hellobank.fr/rsc/contrib/script/hb2/js/app/pages/video-bienvenue.js";
    URL obj = new URL(jsUrl);
    HttpURLConnection cnt = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    cnt.setRequestMethod("GET");
    cnt.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    InputStream stream = cnt.getInputStream();
    if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(cnt.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding"))) {
          stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
    }
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString()); //here is the content of the file you need
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need